# Multiple comment forms on single page/template

Tags: ajax, comments, facebook

I keep reading everywhere that the actual comment:entries tag and comment:form tag should be used on a single entry view template.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/comment/#id38

Anyone had experience in developing something like a facebook feed where multiple comment forms are to be made available along with the users comments for multiple entries?

**UPDATE**

As also suggested by Derek I've tried to do this…

This is the parent

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="posts" status="open|featured"}
            {embed="site/comment" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}`
```

This is the embed being called

```
{embed:entry_id} --THIS GETS PARSED AND I GET THE ID ON FRONTEND
{exp:comment:entries limit="20" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"} --THIS ONE DOESN'T
    <h2 class="comment-user-name">{name}</h2>
    {comment}
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

I just can't get the entry_id from the parent. It seems to not populate the comments tag.
If I hardcode the value in the embed call (eg. `{embed="site/comment" entry_id="3"}`) it works as expected. I suspect is a parsing order issue.

**UPDATE2**

adding a `parse="inward"` parameter to the `{exp:comment:entries}` tag seems to to the trick, but the `{avatar_url`} (i'd love to integrate commenter avatar) seems to point to the avatar of the entry author which is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `comment:entries` and `comment:form` tags accept an `entry_id` parameter, so there's no reason you can't have multiple forms on a page, so long as you pass the correct `entry_id` to each.

You might also run into variable collisions, since you'll need to use them inside of a `channel:entries` loop, so you may need to embed the comments/form and pass the `entry_id` via an embed variable.

**UPDATE:** You'll also need to add `dynamic="no"` to your `comment:entries` tag.

Comment: This is precisely what I did. But it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Try removing `parse="inward"` and adding `dynamic="no"`.